# How do I embed multiple documents in MongoDB using Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a document that has multiple embedded documents but I have been unable to determine the structure for such a document.

I'm using Mongoid in most places but need to perform a batch document insert.

I've tried the following:

```
    def build_records_array(records)
        records.collect do |record|
            record.raw_attributes["identifier"] = record.identifiers.collect { |identifier| identifier.raw_attributes }
            record.raw_attributes
        end
    end # self.build_records_array
```

However the identifiers don't show up as embedded documents when I call insert.  I just get a bunch of garbage in my parent document.

What is the proper structure for embedded documents?

Comment: Are you saving your document after adding new data?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment until now.  I was performing an insert with the array I was building here, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just had a typo.  I wasn't thinking about Mongoid when looking at my problem.  After playing around with the Mongo Driver to retrieve records Mongoid had created I discovered that  I had everything right but the attribute name.

```
def build_records_array(records)
  records.collect do |record|
    record.raw_attributes["identifiers"] = record.identifiers.collect { |identifier| identifier.raw_attributes }
    record.raw_attributes
  end
end # build_records_array
```